# Why am I able to concatenate a String to a null String but not a Character to a null Character?

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, null

I am having a confusion here.
I have String which I have assigned null to it. So when I concat a String anotherString="abc", it prints "nullabc".
But if I try to do the same with a Character, as shown in code, I get a null pointer. I want to understand as to why its happening.
I am new to Java and want to understand the nuances of the language.Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```java
String nullString=null;
Character nullCharacter=null;
Character character=new Character('k');
Integer nullInteger=null;

System.out.println(nullString+"abcdefgh");//prints-"nullabcdefgh"
System.out.println(nullCharacter+character);// throws null pointer exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (actually, in this case, unboxing) to convert the `Character` object to a `char` primitive and it fails since `nullCharacter` is null.

Autoboxing only affects classes that wrap primitives and so it does not apply to `String`.

If you convert the not-null `Character` (named `character` in your code) to a `String`, you will not get `NullPointerException`.

```java
System.out.println(character.toString() + nullCharacter);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Character class is a wrapper class for the `char` primitive type, which is a 16-bit number.

If you add two primitive char variables together, it justs adds the numeric values.

```
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c = (char)(a+b); // c == 'Ã'
```

The `nullCharacter+character` syntax using the Character wrapper object is only possible thanks to auto-unboxing (introduced in Java 1.5). It will implicitly convert it to a numeric addition:

```
    nullCharacter.charValue() + character.charValue() // throws NPE
```

On the other hand, adding two strings together `nullString+"abcdefgh"` is the String concatenation operation which was introduced at the very start of Java, and that operation handles null values differently. In theory it's compiler specific, but most compilers implement it as this:

```
new StringBuilder()
    .append(nullString)  // implicitly converts null to "null"
    .append("abcdefgh")
    .toString()
```

Comment: "`char c = a+b;`" you need a cast in there. Also, it's `charValue()`, not `toCharValue()`.

Comment: understood , didnt know there was auto-unboxing going on in there!